# Bootstrap 4 How to make card body takes vertically remaining space of the viewport with scrollbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

We have this page. Our requirements are:

1. the page itself must **not** have a scroll bar.
2. The card must **fill the remaining space vertically** (even if there is no content in the card-body).
3. The content of the card-body sometime is too long. So we want to have **scroll bar for card-body only**.

We could not achieve the all the requirement without using a fixed height.
If we used a fixed height we will break the 2nd requirement!

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>


    <style>
        body {
            padding-top: 5rem;
        }

        .starter-template {
            padding: 3rem 1.5rem;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .bd-placeholder-img {
            font-size: 1.125rem;
            text-anchor: middle;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
        }

        @media (min-width: 768px) {
            .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
                font-size: 3.5rem;
            }
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

<nav style="" class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault"
            aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown"
                   aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>

<main role="main" class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column">
                <div class="py-2 text-center rounded-top" style="background: rgb(238, 238, 238);">
                    Top Header
                </div>
                <div class="align-self-stretch flex-fill">
                    <div class="card shadow-sm">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            Featured
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p>1</p>
                            <p>1</p>
                            <p>1</p>
                            <p>1</p>
                            <p>1</p>
                            <p>1</p>
                            <p>1</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</main>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/docs/4.6/assets/js/vendor/jquery.slim.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script src="/docs/4.6/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Would you help please?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve with help of `calc()` function of CSS and add predefined `overflow-auto` class in `card-body` div if content over then auto scrollbar will show.

*Helpful Link*
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/overflow/

```css
body {
  padding-top: 5rem;
}
.card-fill{
  height: calc(100vh - 5rem - 1rem); /*reduce padding-top 5rem of body and 1rem for bottom gap*/
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault"
            aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown"
                   aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>

<main role="main" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="card card-fill shadow-sm">
                <div class="card-header">
                    Featured
                </div>
                <div class="card-body overflow-auto">
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore vel corporis excepturi sapiente repellendus cum eius alias, adipisci ut cupiditate quas nesciunt quis accusantium explicabo mollitia consequuntur assumenda laudantium velit cumque. Reprehenderit nobis temporibus fugiat a assumenda deleniti voluptate fuga ex hic nesciunt atque aliquid, soluta obcaecati debitis porro commodi laudantium tempore. Mollitia perspiciatis doloremque expedita neque necessitatibus, ipsam at voluptatum pariatur assumenda, debitis repellat reprehenderit repudiandae sequi similique, quibusdam iusto asperiores non ea. Alias quos, excepturi doloremque enim dolores beatae sed rem, vitae reprehenderit suscipit delectus fuga esse ipsam ipsa sit eveniet, atque laudantium? Deserunt inventore nemo optio quis expedita modi delectus, consequuntur magnam dignissimos ad officiis porro doloribus minima voluptatibus nobis ea, mollitia assumenda fugiat at illum. Et, cumque labore! Sequi magni aperiam rerum minus! Eum ipsam vel labore saepe dicta cupiditate sit nemo voluptatem nesciunt. Quo perferendis eligendi nobis odit nemo totam possimus cupiditate, accusamus placeat laborum, obcaecati eum, voluptatibus sequi ut quisquam numquam praesentium itaque saepe dolorem doloribus dolores cum sed dicta. Iusto debitis eligendi, natus magni dolore facere fugit quod vero enim delectus nostrum distinctio ab tempora aut quisquam. Alias nisi odit veritatis ab eum minima ipsum repudiandae mollitia assumenda, quisquam, tempore consequatur reiciendis dolorem dicta corporis accusantium a. Inventore, harum quidem, expedita commodi ea sunt delectus ut, aspernatur cupiditate officia voluptatibus quis sequi aliquam ipsa praesentium dicta recusandae ipsum in odio obcaecati aperiam nesciunt dolorem non porro. Dignissimos ipsa unde impedit quos eius dolores fuga quas dolorum quae culpa quam ex, voluptatibus nesciunt nostrum iure obcaecati minima numquam saepe earum modi explicabo excepturi beatae, aut esse. Ab esse distinctio quasi facere aspernatur eligendi vel dignissimos error voluptates ipsa, sequi corrupti unde, magni rerum et, eveniet animi voluptatem cupiditate! Illum, dolor necessitatibus. Aperiam optio dolor at dolores autem numquam. Quasi aperiam harum magnam pariatur fuga iusto incidunt sapiente expedita laboriosam magni voluptatibus molestiae, ex tenetur similique non voluptate quibusdam cum! Eveniet atque animi assumenda id ab rem officiis omnis, hic sapiente quidem soluta nihil, consequuntur sint. Incidunt eum voluptas praesentium nesciunt deserunt qui nemo, animi nihil! Voluptas natus officia maxime inventore facilis id dolorem odit molestiae ut provident, placeat aspernatur laudantium quis modi deserunt, quasi mollitia blanditiis earum nisi illo animi! Quos reprehenderit excepturi obcaecati incidunt fugiat beatae, laborum debitis quae architecto quibusdam quaerat porro nemo natus ipsum sint cupiditate aliquam suscipit velit quis rem esse temporibus. Iste similique excepturi autem tempore sit. Harum tempore tempora molestias nihil labore, ipsam sequi quia ipsum, inventore minus cumque consequatur dolores, ex aliquam. Enim quis excepturi temporibus velit laboriosam ducimus! Ipsam, ad unde suscipit necessitatibus iusto in neque voluptates quod dolorem! Nihil sed eum tenetur dolor aut nulla ipsum quidem fugit totam! Iure dicta est inventore velit in quibusdam debitis ducimus a, aspernatur enim omnis sequi dolorum eius provident voluptas culpa officia nisi labore reprehenderit? Facilis placeat quas, commodi aut tenetur esse corrupti reiciendis debitis nesciunt reprehenderit tempora provident eveniet? In, ex. Animi repellat necessitatibus error perspiciatis, commodi delectus rerum aspernatur, blanditiis numquam ullam exercitationem sint! Expedita possimus quod ex, veritatis non quas voluptates itaque fugit dignissimos dolore earum neque consequuntur laboriosam quia, maxime aperiam iure at iste suscipit culpa, asperiores doloremque cumque! Facere saepe odio eos eligendi, quis quas nam, molestias soluta atque maiores cum dolorem, dolorum iste harum consequuntur! Nihil voluptatum tempore cum mollitia deserunt? A aperiam impedit, aliquid illo ipsa similique numquam non enim repudiandae quasi quaerat odit corporis voluptates unde autem ex incidunt nisi veritatis soluta repellendus, accusantium molestias quae id. Voluptatem quisquam amet iure iste esse, sequi ex maiores soluta natus est, debitis provident aut adipisci, commodi et ullam totam labore id. Dignissimos ea fuga modi iure quasi nesciunt, ipsum incidunt! Nemo error qui hic culpa. Quaerat, repellat fuga a nam doloribus odio deleniti dolor, dignissimos veniam, debitis error voluptatem. Animi ullam dolores itaque, quidem sapiente fuga, deleniti iure illo ea autem, id alias cumque explicabo a quia ratione nihil odit deserunt eius distinctio suscipit dignissimos. Deserunt nesciunt assumenda eum alias fugiat natus quibusdam cumque dolorem placeat dignissimos distinctio, rerum consequuntur ipsam. Dignissimos ullam voluptatum quisquam voluptas assumenda pariatur ex totam at enim unde dolore, non natus itaque omnis voluptate illum veniam necessitatibus, error, repellendus facere deserunt? Saepe soluta mollitia iste commodi, doloribus similique, aliquam recusandae eligendi officiis delectus maxime quos? Quam at quo non dolores? Voluptas tenetur rerum error eos quo quam in, excepturi odio doloremque vero a rem beatae adipisci itaque ratione blanditiis. Temporibus, porro aperiam id eius, molestiae quas deserunt perspiciatis magni numquam autem maxime consequuntur provident error inventore mollitia soluta nobis enim voluptatem! Dicta facere similique tempore libero nesciunt tempora magni quas atque commodi culpa quaerat nam voluptatum vero iste at quis, hic perferendis debitis nulla accusamus voluptatibus repellat! Temporibus voluptatum at in accusantium labore officiis? Necessitatibus, quasi obcaecati. Saepe, odit! Temporibus in voluptate minus soluta obcaecati tempore sed, quas necessitatibus iste quasi, illum ipsa quos provident. Tempora ipsa ad, mollitia delectus quas possimus iure beatae tempore eaque, ab non sint ut itaque nobis ullam molestiae fugit adipisci totam quod obcaecati id. A, quas obcaecati perferendis cum laborum soluta, quo dolores sapiente ipsam explicabo nam voluptatum molestiae nesciunt? Labore nulla quos ad architecto ab laborum aliquid assumenda ipsam magni non veritatis, at possimus suscipit eos recusandae consectetur numquam hic accusantium nesciunt. Tempore magni sunt itaque iste? Magni quidem consequuntur in adipisci nesciunt, qui cum ut et quis, sit ducimus, facere reprehenderit unde neque? Facilis atque nam quod! Asperiores ex eius tempora molestiae ducimus harum rem ipsam hic nihil magni, dolorem, doloribus illum veniam laborum amet quae sit in impedit neque quod ullam nostrum est. Reiciendis temporibus nulla nostrum? In itaque iste consequatur a veniam, atque voluptas velit labore nulla autem tempore, corrupti omnis. Qui modi, ab voluptate laborum repellendus dignissimos molestiae inventore similique quas recusandae necessitatibus aspernatur repellat, blanditiis voluptatem porro tenetur illo? Id iure pariatur nesciunt. Quo eligendi earum reprehenderit praesentium atque sunt accusantium fugit tempora, alias delectus accusamus consequatur veniam quos, debitis asperiores illum vel optio recusandae, maxime aperiam eveniet in ab ut nesciunt. Officia temporibus, illum quidem recusandae vel laborum dolores veritatis quae aut, eum quo iusto quibusdam reprehenderit error eos, corrupti nisi atque fugit ea velit blanditiis. Eaque hic voluptas, quis expedita, similique quasi modi adipisci voluptate dignissimos voluptatum reiciendis provident saepe ex nam aliquid nobis. Fugit saepe magnam, cupiditate obcaecati iusto alias numquam rem dolore maiores veritatis vitae debitis provident quos asperiores consequuntur nobis aliquam incidunt ipsum eos dolor velit aliquid. Dolorem inventore neque explicabo alias optio esse aut cum rem ex ipsa. A, sapiente nam velit perferendis ipsam distinctio soluta mollitia ullam? Ipsam quasi autem id doloribus, atque explicabo provident iure voluptates! Beatae nisi vel eum quidem, esse deserunt, nihil accusamus aliquid tempore, et distinctio ut totam illo excepturi voluptas vero maxime eaque itaque minus magni omnis sit. Error animi debitis, optio expedita dignissimos suscipit. Repellendus ea molestiae libero sint perferendis, saepe aliquid obcaecati, natus a quia sed quisquam ex quasi illum, incidunt ad nisi quo vero praesentium. Error excepturi ipsam iste repudiandae ad quidem deserunt debitis minus earum asperiores corporis, reiciendis in aperiam dolorem reprehenderit animi rerum. Aperiam maxime porro aliquam accusamus repudiandae odio eligendi nisi ipsa quod minus at temporibus, labore fuga deserunt et illum repellat. Minima beatae eligendi, quis illo consectetur reiciendis labore voluptates quam dolorem natus dolor autem tempore nulla, a dolorum consequatur eum explicabo necessitatibus molestiae exercitationem. Veritatis nisi hic magni itaque dicta architecto enim. Quis a rerum odit incidunt sed reprehenderit blanditiis quaerat ipsum recusandae. Reiciendis, culpa recusandae illum itaque doloribus eaque molestiae nesciunt quam quis non, officiis consectetur perspiciatis? Saepe sint, sequi dolor harum, maiores illo, sit nemo numquam ratione delectus asperiores voluptatibus. Ipsum, nulla sint! Illo quaerat quas fugiat itaque consectetur magni quidem tempora molestiae voluptate? Ipsam, illo. Amet consequatur nulla facilis enim molestiae quas illum doloremque, ducimus id aut nostrum, nesciunt ea quasi quaerat minima neque perferendis officiis omnis corrupti officia! Vitae doloribus velit, est, facere rem aperiam, tempora quis nisi explicabo harum rerum dicta incidunt! Distinctio est nam expedita ipsam dicta illo quibusdam deserunt autem. Fugiat quisquam minima cumque qui voluptas animi, eaque ex voluptatum sunt laudantium sint, reiciendis quam vero, quaerat quasi accusamus rem quia. Ullam, iste. Culpa eveniet quidem nisi non, sed facilis ipsa iure. Perferendis consectetur hic expedita corporis, minima saepe doloremque tempore. Dolorem quasi soluta repellat nulla. Aut quasi ex aliquam nemo tenetur maiores, nesciunt omnis natus laborum, dolor iure. Quos fugiat hic, excepturi laudantium neque omnis, doloribus enim eligendi impedit, earum cupiditate ea harum eius sit asperiores similique ducimus! Accusantium sequi beatae rem neque, rerum magnam sed expedita libero fuga ipsa odio non sit vero quis quos voluptatem. Dolorem libero deserunt magni quos cupiditate. Omnis nobis, et voluptas laboriosam asperiores aut. Voluptates ipsum ea accusamus molestias distinctio ut totam voluptate, nulla a eos nihil nam asperiores quos praesentium ab et nesciunt autem expedita, harum, consequatur vero saepe! Eveniet ea ipsa veniam, expedita molestias facere ab architecto veritatis, voluptatum culpa fuga similique tempore, repellat voluptatem iste laborum? Rerum minus nostrum sit odit, quis praesentium eligendi vitae non aut vel recusandae maxime velit similique aperiam facere? Provident, natus. Autem, iste eligendi eos ipsam dolore fugiat aliquid, sit quod architecto, expedita dolorem. Magnam, tempora? Inventore sunt deleniti tenetur, libero molestias hic ad eius. Mollitia cupiditate sapiente ad tenetur consequuntur quo cum non quisquam a, nam facilis sed necessitatibus ullam perferendis odio quis suscipit rem velit incidunt iure ipsa voluptatem at doloremque ipsam. Minima repellendus nulla cum recusandae officia illo numquam at reiciendis expedita assumenda, facilis eum commodi sint totam harum asperiores qui facere similique adipisci deserunt labore doloremque nesciunt reprehenderit? Soluta numquam adipisci ut laboriosamofficia. Debitis, eius.<br><br>
                        Last Line
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```